# Jbutton too big java

Tags: java, swing, size, jbutton, gridbaglayout

I'm having a hard time with **JButtons**, and I have two problems.

1. The first is that I have set some proportions in my frame with `GridBagLayout` to set the size of a `JPanel`. Nothing strange so far. The program shows the space in which the panel I want to add should stay. I would like to have some 20 disposed in this space, fitting its dimension and respecting its proportions. But when I created my `JPanel` with the buttons with another `GridBagLayout` and `weightx` and `weighty` all set to `1`, the result was that the new grid went out from the space I wanted it to fit in and that the program showed before.
   **Why don't buttons resize to fit their space while other `JComponents`** (like `JLabel`s, `JTextField`s and horizontal/vertical struts) **do?**
2. The second question regards the button **text dimension**. My buttons have the default font, but when I try to enlarge the text size, the buttons show "`...`", despite there is space for a larger text dimension. How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

PS: I think the first problem depends on the second.

---

***EDIT:***
As I thought, the first problem derived from the second. I found a method to solve the second problem and now everything works. YAY!

Comment: Got an runnable example the demonstrates your problems?

Comment: i could post my code but it's very long and probably not the best in the world because I'm new to Java.swing.. but if you want to see it I will post it

Comment: Just create a small example that demonstrates your particular problem...

Comment: @ProTom Hey, I'm really glad that you solved your problem! But... would you mind posting an answer describing how you dealt with it? That would be helpful for the community :)

Comment: Yes, of course. The problem was so difficult to explain as easy to solve... I forgot to set the space between the inner text and the border of the Jbuttons using setMargin(), so that java used the default margins and resized the buttons to respect that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

frame.setlayout(null);
thats the thing that helped me